# Am I missing anything in my steps to move my WordPress site to another server?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, iis, windows-server-2008, web-deployment

I have 2 servers, both Windows Server 2008, both with MySQL on them, and one of them is currently hosting a live WordPress site that I want to move to the other server. While I'm waiting for files to copy over, I want to know if there's anything wrong or missing about my steps.

1. I installed WordPress on the server I intend to move the site to.
2. I deleted all the source files that were created in the physical path of the new site, excluding `wp-config.php` and `web.config`, which I saved.
3. I copied all of my site's source files to the physical path of the new site. I overwrote the `wp-config.php` and `web.config` with the ones I saved in step 2.
4. With the MySQL command interface, I navigated to the database that WordPress will run on in the new server, then ran source `oldDbQuery.sql`, which is a query that generates my site's database
5. Using IIS, I removed the bindings the site had on the old server, and added them on the new server
6. Went to my Domain Name Services manager and changed the domains (equivalent to the bindings in step 5) to point to my new server

Is there anything wrong with that process?

Answer (score 0):

Step 4 doesn't specify whether or not a MYSQL user was created with grant permissions applied to the new database.

Also, if your site uses SSL, you will need to install your certs on the new server and configure bindings for port 443.